# How to send BTC from my coinbase account using shell script in android only

Tags: adb

Please i am thinking of automating BTC send from my coinbase account to another coinbase user via email. I read coinbase API documentations and the only thing that is close to what I need is the script below:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/2ccf394c-193b-5b2a-9155-3b4732659yam/transactions/
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer abd90df5f27a7b170cd775abf89d632b350b7c1c9d53e08b340cd9832ce52c2c' \
  -d '{
    "type": "send",
    "to": "EMAIL_ADDRESS",
    "amount": "ALL_SATOSHI",
    "currency": "BTC",
    "idem": "9316dd16-0c05"
  }'
```

but it is not working at all when I wrote it in a script named "send.sh" it says "-X" not found, and some other stuffs. Please how can I get this working only in android, all I need is a script that once I execute it I will get the specified Satoshi amount in the coinbase account that has the associated email address specified as the receiver. And there is no API key and API secret specified in the script, I don't know if that is the problem.
Please can someone help me provide a solution please, I sincerely appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're determined to play with Bitcoin... You seem to be missing a backslash at the end of your second line.

```
#!/system/bin/sh
curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/2ccf394c-193b-5b2a-9155-3b4732659yam/transactions/ \
  -X POST \
...
```